# jsoup library not found in Eclipse with Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I am building a JavaFX project in Eclipse Oxygen.3, release 4.7.3.

With jdk-9.0.4 I get class not found errors on jsoup library imports but when I revert back to jdk-1.8.0_45 the errors go away.

I have the jsoup library in a lib folder under my project root, and the Java build path correctly references it.

With Java 8 the library works, with Java 9 I get the errors, with nothing else changed in the project settings, library location or my code.

Is there something about Jsoup that can't work with Java 9, or am I just missing a step somewhere?

Thanks, Jerry

Comment: What errors? Show a stack trace.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not requiring the module.

Comment: So what exactly should I do to correct the problem?

Comment: I have just now created a test project with jsoup-1.11.2.jar in a lib folder in the project root.  When the project is set to use the JRE System Library in jdk-9.0.4,, all imports from org.jsoup are flagged by Eclipse as "The import org.jsoup.Connection cannot be resolved." When I change the JRE to the library in jdk1.8.0_162, the flags instantly disappear and the code runs.  (The Java 9 JRE appears under Modulepath in the Eclipse properties window, Java 8 under Classpath. Modulepath appears to be new in Eclipse Oxygen. Where do I find a setting that would require the module?)

Comment: Stacktrace? Ha! I should be so lucky.  See comment above. Program won't launch, much less show a stacktrace.

Comment: Okay, problem solved. Thanks for the pointer, Jacob, your reference to required modules led me to the solution---the JRE for Java 9 is automatically placed under the modules node in the build path properties tab, but I put the jsoup jar under the classpath node. Moving it to modules did the trick. It now works.